# Moving navigation bar's dropdown's overflow

Tags: html, css

So I made a navigation bar with some drop-down links, my problem is that when I hover over the link to open the dropdown it overflows to the right and since the button is on the right end of the navbar it makes the scrollbar appear. How would I make it so the link in the drop-down starts from the right side?

[image]

```css
    .navbar {
     list-style-type: none;
     overflow: hidden;
     background: #3498db;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #2c3e50;
    }
    
    .navbar-item {
     float: left;
    }
    
    .navbar-item.right {
     float: right;
    }
    
    .navbar-link {
     display: block;
     color: #ecf0f1;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 14px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .navbar-link:hover, .navbar-link.active, .dropdown-content a:hover, .dropdown-content a.active {
     background: #2980b9;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     background-color: #3498db;
     box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     min-width: 120px;
     z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
     color: #ecf0f1;
     padding: 12px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: block;
     text-align: left;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
     display: block;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
     .navbar-item.right, .navbar-item {
      float: none;
     }
    }
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
     <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#" class="navbar-link active">Home</a></li>
     <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#" class="navbar-link">{PH}</a></li>
     <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#" class="navbar-link">{PH}</a></li>
     <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#" class="navbar-link">{PH}</a></li>
     <li class="navbar-item dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navbar-link">{PH}</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="#">{PH}</a>
       <a href="#">{PH}</a>
       <a href="#">{PH}</a>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li class="navbar-item dropdown right" id="membersbtn">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navbar-link">Members</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="#">Register</a>
       <a href="#">Log In</a>
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: do you have any live link ? or can you create any online demo to reflect your issue

Comment: Yes I do, here https://dev.corestudios.me @Rahul

Comment: I know my problem is with the min-width but if I remove it the links will be too short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content { right:0px;}`

```css
    .navbar {
     list-style-type: none;
     overflow: hidden;
     background: #3498db;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #2c3e50;
    }
    
    .navbar-item {
     float: left;
    }
    
    .navbar-item.right {
     float: right;
    }
    
    .navbar-link {
     display: block;
     color: #ecf0f1;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 14px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .navbar-link:hover, .navbar-link.active, .dropdown-content a:hover, .dropdown-content a.active {
     background: #2980b9;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     background-color: #3498db;
     box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     min-width: 120px;
     z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
     color: #ecf0f1;
     padding: 12px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: block;
     text-align: left;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
     display: block;
        right:0px; /*Add this*/
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
     .navbar-item.right, .navbar-item {
      float: none;
     }
    }
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
     <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#" class="navbar-link active">Home</a></li>
     <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#" class="navbar-link">{PH}</a></li>
     <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#" class="navbar-link">{PH}</a></li>
     <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#" class="navbar-link">{PH}</a></li>
     <li class="navbar-item dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navbar-link">{PH}</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="#">{PH}</a>
       <a href="#">{PH}</a>
       <a href="#">{PH}</a>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li class="navbar-item dropdown right" id="membersbtn">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navbar-link">Members</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="#">Register</a>
       <a href="#">Log In</a>
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add

```
.navbar-item.right .dropdown-content {
    right: 0;
}
```

see below ex:

```css
    .navbar {
     list-style-type: none;
     overflow: hidden;
     background: #3498db;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #2c3e50;
    }
    
    .navbar-item {
     float: left;
    }
    
    .navbar-item.right {
     float: right;
    }
    
    .navbar-link {
     display: block;
     color: #ecf0f1;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 14px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .navbar-link:hover, .navbar-link.active, .dropdown-content a:hover, .dropdown-content a.active {
     background: #2980b9;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     background-color: #3498db;
     box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     min-width: 120px;
     z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
     color: #ecf0f1;
     padding: 12px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: block;
     text-align: left;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
     display: block;
    }
.navbar-item.right .dropdown-content {
right: 0;
}
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
     .navbar-item.right, .navbar-item {
      float: none;
     }
    }
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
     <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#" class="navbar-link active">Home</a></li>
     <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#" class="navbar-link">{PH}</a></li>
     <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#" class="navbar-link">{PH}</a></li>
     <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#" class="navbar-link">{PH}</a></li>
     <li class="navbar-item dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navbar-link">{PH}</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="#">{PH}</a>
       <a href="#">{PH}</a>
       <a href="#">{PH}</a>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li class="navbar-item dropdown right" id="membersbtn">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navbar-link">Members</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="#">Register</a>
       <a href="#">Log In</a>
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you aswell :)